# QNetworkAccessManager reliable connection in QT

Tags: qt, networking, qnetworkaccessmanager

I'm trying to use post and get methods to communicate with remote server in QT client application.After creating connection using QNetworkAccessManager, how can i guarantee that whether my connection is alive or closed?

Comment: You will get errors (via signals), that something goes wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `QNetworkReply::error()` after sending request. If no error occured than this function returns `QNetworkReply::NoError`

Comment: Thanks people for your replies